# How do I migrate to UTC hardware clock?

Tags: time

I have been using local time hardware clock because of sharing the machine with a Windows system. Now I don't use Windows any actively and would like to set the hardware clock to UTC. How to reconfigure this in Ubuntu?

PS: I use XUbuntu actually, so I'd like a command-line-based desktop-agnostic solution.

Answer (score 11):

Edit the file `/etc/default/rcS` with your favorite text editor, ie:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/rcS
```

[image]

Look for the *UTC=foo* (yes/no) line and change it to *UTC=yes*.

From the [`rcS(5) man page`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man5/rcS.5.html):

> **UTC**
>   This is used to govern how  the  hardware  real  time  clock  is interpreted when it is read (e.g., at boot time, for the purpose of setting the system clock) and when it is  written  (e.g.,  at shutdown).  If this option is set to no then the system clock is
>                 assumed to be set to local time.  If the option is  set  to  yes then the system clock is assumed to be set to something approximating Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).  (POSIX systems keep  a variant of UTC, without leap seconds.)

Comment: Please note that in recent Ubuntu versions (since at least 16.04) the UTC setting is no longer there in `/etc/default/rcS`. Use `/etc/adjtime` instead (replace LOCAL with UTC there) or better use `hwclock` tool to change the file.